# Data insert in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongodb-query, backend

I am learning MongoDB and node.js. And when I am working on inserting the data into MongoDB, It will give me an error.

The error photo with the code is given below.

**DB_Connect file**

```
const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");
const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017";
const Client = new MongoClient(url);
const database = "parmesh";
const collection = 'first'

const connect_db = async () => {
     let result = await Client.connect();
     let db = result.db(database);
     return db.collection(collection);
     // let data = await collection.find({name:'Kalpeshkumar'}).toArray();
     // console.log('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQR')
     // console.log('new data', data)
     // console.log(collection)
};

module.exports = connect_db
// module.exports = collection
```

**Insert_Data file**

```
const dbConnect = require('./DB_Connection')
const collection = 'first'

const insert = async () => {
     const datab = await dbConnect()
     const result = datab.collection.insertOne({name: "Maunil", age: "12"}, (err, res)=>{
          if(!err){
               console.log('Inserted')
          }else{
               console.log(err)
          }
     });
}
insert()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ciK0p.png)

Please anybody give me some solution!
Your help is world to me right now.

I am learning MongoDB and node.js. And when I am working on inserting the data into MongoDB, It will give me an error.

The error photo with the code is given below.

Comment: The result of `connect_db` appears to be a collection rather than a database. But then you attempt to do `.collection` again on that object on the `.insertOne()` like. Remove one of the references to `.collection`